# Not able to access data variable in script after populating it with json from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Today I been trying out Vue, and have been trying to run before I can walk, so I have been running into walls once in a while. I asked a couple questions earlier and am back with another one.

The last question I asked was 'Not able to access data variable in script but can in html', and the issue was a typo. Once that typo was fixed then I was able to access the data variable that I populated with an array in the script, but now I am running into an issue with populating the data variable by using ajax and a promise, while I can access it in the html, I can't access the variable's data in the script now and I double checked that I have no typo's.

What I am not understanding is why if the json string is in a local variable then I can access the said data variable, but not after its populated by using ajax

Now I get errors and can't access the variable...

Here is my ajax call:

```
GetItemPriceListByID: (whichOne) => {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../Scripts/" + whichOne + "JSON.json",
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

Here is a copy of the JSON being returned

```
[
  {
    "CatalogName": "Retro Doors",
    "ItemName": "French Doors",
    "ItemListPrice": "$461.00",
    "ItemType": "Oak",
    "ItemFeatures": [
      {
        "Features": "Door Quantity",
        "QTY": 2
      },
      {
        "Features": "Door Hinges",
        "QTY": 4
      },
      {
        "Features": "Door Knobs",
        "QTY": 1
      },
      {
        "Features": "Door Looks",
        "QTY": 1
      },
      {
        "Features": "Glass Panes",
        "QTY": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The HTML:
    
        
            {{ item.CatalogName }}
            
                {{ items.Features }}

the script:

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        beforeCreate: function () {
            console.log("Before Created");
        },
        created: function () {
            console.log("Created");
            this.GetItemsList();
        },
        beforeMount: function () {
            console.log("Before Mount");
        },
        data: {
            itemPriceList: []
        },
        methods: {
            GetItemsList() {
                this.itemPriceList = CommonFunctions.GetItemPriceListByID("ItemList")
                    .done(data => {
                        this.itemPriceList = data;
                        console.log("Completed")
                    }); //result;
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            console.log("Mounted");
            console.log(this.itemPriceList[0].CatalogName);
        }
    });
```

Errors that I am getting with this (if ran then CatalogName does show up in the HTML)

[image: Error Image]

** EDIT **

[image: console.log]

Comment: what about `console.log(this.itemPriceList)`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim,  I just added a screen shot of what console.log(this.itemPriceList) returns

Comment: please in that console try to expand `responseJSON`

Comment: There is data in the responseJSON, but I can't access it. I tried
console.log(this.itemPriceList.responseJSON[0].CatalogName) and I get an error back Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Comment: i think that the assignment `this.itemPriceList = CommonFunction ...` is not correct, try this `CommonFunction...`

Comment: Ah ok, yes you are right about the assignment because its already done in the .done, but when I do console.log(this.itemPriceList) when mounted I am getting [__ob__: Observer] with a length of zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182689/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-chris).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data object add a property called itemPromise

```
   GetItemsList() { 
          this.itemPromise = CommonFunctions.GetItemPriceListByID("ItemList").done(); 
     }
```

in the mounted hook add this :

```
    this.itemPromise.then((res)=>{this.itemPriceList=res})
```

**UPDATE**

in the `created` hook we had created a Promise object by calling the `GetItemsList()` and assigning that promise to `itemPromise` property, in the `mounted` hook we use the `itemPromise.then(res=>{...})` to assign the result to our `itemPriceList` property

Answer (score 3):

`this.GetItemsList()` is being called in created, but is an asynchronous method, so Vue continues to call the rest of the lifecycle hooks.

Whats happening is "mounted" is being called before the Ajax call returns, so the list is empty.

Try this:

```
GetItemsList() {
            this.itemPriceList = CommonFunctions.GetItemPriceListByID("ItemList")
                .done(data => {
                    this.itemPriceList = data;
                    console.log("Completed")

                    console.log(this.itemPriceList)
                    // Additional logic here

                }); //result;
        }
```

Any logic dependant on itemPriceList being set should be added inside the arrow function, or as additional methods that are called inside the arrow function.

Comment: All I was trying to do was populate the itemPriceList with the json array and still access it within the script. In normal JS we can populate a variable and continue to access the data in it. But its not working that way in here

Comment: Ajax requests are asynchronous, so you need to wait for the call to complete before the data is available.

Comment: That explains why I see the console.log('completed') after the mount is done

Comment: I tried just using a normal ajax call and had async set to false and that didnt work either, but why does the v-for work in the html without issue?

Comment: My guess is that async:false was not set correctly (Check your console to see the order of function calls).

The v-for basically works by watching the variable for changes, and only triggers when that variable is changed. (Ex: setting the array to the ajax response)